# SWTBot for Lotus Notes java plugin testing

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes, swtbot

Is it possible to use SWTBot to make automatic GUI tests for Lotus Notes Eclipse Java plugins?

EDIT: If yes, how exactly to integrate a `Client Services Run Configuration` with a `SWTBot Test Run Configuration` in Eclipse? Certain attributes like the Personality framework can't be added to a SWTBot Test Run Config...
[image]

If not, is there a GUI Testing Framework that works well with Lotus Notes?

Thanks

P.S. In the bowels of the Internet I found [this link](https://jira4.xored.com/browse/QS-1628) where it seems QF Test integration was not successful

Comment: how is this question off-topic? Is there something I should improve?

Answer (score 0):

Since Lotus Notes is an Eclipse RCP application (as far as I know), it's totally possible to use SWTBot with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's a mix of C, C++ code and it includes the RCP framework as well. I will give it a try in the end

Comment: Tried, can't figure out how to configure the launch config for it :-/ Have you ever done it?

Comment: I never tried. Does Lotus Notes plugin development allow to run UI tests ? If yes, the steps would be the same except that 1. SWTBot needs to be added to the target platform and 2. SWTBot tests must run in regular (non-UI) thread.

Comment: I can't make the launch configuration launch, despite including SWTBot into the target platform